# How do I return more images as touchableOpacities as long as theres images left in the array?

Tags: arrays, image, react-native

Uploading the first image works fine but uploading multiple images isnt possible. It just overwrites eachother.

How do I return multiple images? and how can I slice in the array?

```
state = {
    image: [],
 };

 _renderImages() {
    return this.state.image.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
    this._deleteSpecificImage(index)}>
                <Image
                    key={index}
                    source={{ uri: item }}
                    style={styles.image}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    });
}


_deleteSpecificImage = (index) => {
    const { image } = this.state
    image.splice(index)

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a second parameter to the splice function which is an amount you want to remove [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Also, you have to set images array to the state back. Like this

```
  _deleteSpecificImage = index => {
    const { image } = this.state;
    image.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ image })
  };
```

check it with [expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@troublediehard/d7f30f)